# Javascript monkey patch the rethinkdb .run

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I have rethinkdb instance, that i use by nodejs client.

```
rethinkdb
  .db(p.rdb_database)
  .table(p.table)
  .orderBy({index: 'uidAndDate'})
  .filter({})
  .run(rethinkdbConnection, function (error, cursor) {...})
```

is there any way to monkey patch the `.run` function?
I want to monitor the rethinkdb client like this - add `before` function

```
rethinkdb
  .db(p.rdb_database)
  .table(p.table)
  .orderBy({index: 'uidAndDate'})
  .filter({})
  .before(function(error, query, result, next){
    console.log('query: ',query);
    console.log('result: ',result);
    next(error);
  })
  .run(rethinkdbConnection, function (error, cursor) {...})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monkey patch it, with something like this

```
TermBase = r.expr(1).constructor.__super__.constructor.__super__
TermBase.run_copy = TermBase.run;
Termbase.run = function(callback) {
    console.log("query", this.toString());
    this.run_copy(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
        else {
            console.log("result", result)
        }
        callback(error, result)
    })
})
```

But that's kind of dirty.